# How to select the value i want from more than 4 multiple option

Tags: php, select

```html
<h1> <font size=20% color=black>Room Choice </font><br></h1>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                 <hr />
                </div>
    <table width ="1100" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th><font size=4 color=black>Room Type</font></th>
        <th><font size=4 color=black>Description</font></th>
        <th><font size=4 color=black>Room(Cost)</font></th>
        <th><font size=4 color=black>Date</font></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></td>
        <td><p style="color:Black;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>&nbsp;Single Bed</a></p>
        <font size=3 color=black>-Only provide 1 single bed.<br>
        -Max for 1 guest only.</font></td>
    <td><select name="sBed" class="available_rooms_ddl">
    <option value="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="1-55">1 (55.00$)</option>
    <option value="2-110">2 (110.00$)</option>
    <option value="3-165">3 (165.00$)</option>
    <option value="4-220">4 (220.00$)</option>
    <option value="5-275">5 (275.00$)</option>
    <option value="6-330">6 (330.00$)</option>
    <option value="7-385">7 (385.00$)</option>
    <option value="8-440">8 (440.00$)</option>
    <option value="9-495">9 (495.00$)</option>
    <option value="10-550">10 (550.00$)</option></select></td>
        <td>From:<?php echo $checkIn = test_input($_POST["checkIn"]); ?><br> To:<?php echo $checkOut = test_input($_POST["checkOut"]); ?> </td></tr>
         <td><img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></td>
        <td><p style="color:Black;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>&nbsp;2 Single Bed</a></p>
        <font size=3 color=black>-Provide 2 single bed.<br>
        -Max for 2 guest only.</font></td>
        <td><select name="tSBed" class="available_rooms_ddl">
    <option value="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="1-80">1 (80.00$)</option>
    <option value="2-160">2 (160.00$)</option>
    <option value="3-240">3 (240.00$)</option>
    <option value="4-320">4 (320.00$)</option>
    <option value="5-400">5 (400.00$)</option>
    <option value="6-480">6 (480.00$)</option>
    <option value="7-560">7 (560.00$)</option>
    <option value="8-640">8 (640.00$)</option>
    <option value="9-720">9 (720.00$)</option>
    <option value="10-800">10 (800.00$)</option></select></td>
         <td>From:<?php echo $checkIn = test_input($_POST["checkIn"]); ?><br> To:<?php echo $checkOut = test_input($_POST["checkOut"]); ?> </td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></td>
        <td><p style="color:Black;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>&nbsp;Double Bed</a></p>
        <font size=3 color=black>-Only provide 1 double bed.<br>
        -Max for 2 guest only.</font></td>
        <td><select name="dBed" class="available_rooms_ddl">
    <option value="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="1-140">1 (140.00$)</option>
    <option value="2-280">2 (280.00$)</option>
    <option value="3-420">3 (420.00$)</option>
    <option value="4-560">4 (560.00$)</option>
    <option value="5-700">5 (700.00$)</option></select></td>
         <td>From:<?php echo $checkIn = test_input($_POST["checkIn"]); ?><br> To:<?php echo $checkOut = test_input($_POST["checkOut"]); ?> </td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="4.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0"></td>
        <td><p style="color:Black;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>&nbsp;4-Bed Domitary</a></p>
        <font size=3 color=black>-Provide 4 single bed.<br>
        -Max for 4 guest only.</font></td>
        <td><select name="fBed" class="available_rooms_ddl">
    <option value="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="1-30">1 (30.00$)</option>
    <option value="2-60">2 (60.00$)</option>
    <option value="3-90">3 (90.00$)</option>
    <option value="4-120">4 (120.00$)</option>
    <option value="5-150">5 (150.00$)</option>
    <option value="6-180">6 (180.00$)</option>
    <option value="7-210">7 (210.00$)</option>
    <option value="8-240">8 (240.00$)</option>
    <option value="9-270">9 (270.00$)</option>
    <option value="10-300">10 (300.00$)</option>
    <option value="11-330">11 (330.00$)</option>
    <option value="12-360">12 (360.00$)</option></select></td>
```

I want to select from these 4 option..what step should i need to do so that it can differentiate which selection that i choose among these 4 option?
i searched many post and non related..i hope someone can teach me because i am new to PHP
BUT please DONT set is as duplicated or what because none of such question asked before.

EDIT2: Many might confused about my question. Well,my question is the user will choose the option to reserve for their room. select name is the type of room and the option is the number of room that user want
For example 
`<select name="sBed" class="available_rooms_ddl">` -> this "sBed" is the type of room : single bed room. 
`<option value="2-110">2 (110.00$)</option>` -> this option with value 2-110 is the number of room that user choose =2 and cost 110$. So my question is...what method should i use to detect the type of room and the number of room that choosen by the user

Comment: should i use the variable to each of the option? and detect if the value = 0 then ignore the option?

Comment: 'these 4 options'? you have 11 options. so confused. do you mean select up to 4 options?

Comment: i mean each selection having some option...among these all option in each selection,only 1 option among these 4 selection will be chosen.

Comment: Its little confusing about what you are asking. Either be a little clear. Because your English is little weak and we cannot understand what you need to do. But what i understood you need someone to slect only four option and aftere that he cannot choose any option. Check for multi select box. Where you can choose more than one option and you can give the number of options they can choose

Comment: <select name="sBed" class="available_rooms_ddl"> ->
this "sBed" is the type of room : single bed room.
<option value="2-110">2 (110.00$)</option> ->
this option with value 2-110 is the number of room that user choose =2 and cost 110$.
So my question is...what method should i use to detect the type of room and the number of room that choosen by the user

Comment: anyone can teach me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please put if you need **multiple** option from each select box

```
<select name="sBed[]" multiple>
```

then from form action php page you can get

> $sBed= $_POST['sBed']; print_r ($sBed);

similarly Other three also

Hope this will solve your issue